# How Jane/John/Baby and Barkeep/Agent Doe/Fizzle Bomber were connected in the "Predestination" ending?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, predestination

After watching ["Predestination (2014)"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2397535/), I could understand that:

> Jane, John & their orphaned baby were the same person; -- played by the actress Sarah Snook

Similarly:

> the barkeeper, Agent Doe & their older self "fizzle bomber" were also the same person; -- played by the actor Ethan Hawke

But by showing the operation scars on the agent Doe's body, it was revealed that even:

> the heroine (first set of 3) & the hero (second set of 3) were also the same person!

No plausible explanation was given for that plot twist.
How can they turn out to be the same!?

Comment: Do any of these answer your question? [Why does The Bartender have surgery marks?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27696/1006), [Predestination ending scene](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27568/1006), [How does 'Agent Doe' end up where he does in Predestination?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/93155/1006)

Comment: Also related: [How was the baby born in the start?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/46196/1006)

Comment: Please be sure to VTC as duplicate of a duplicate *question*, not based on answers!